# Sort values alphabetically and concatenate them to array using SPARQL

Tags: arrays, sorting, sparql

Is there a way to sort the values alphabetically and then concatenate them into an array using SPARQL. I am new to SPARQL and looking for ways to do it.

For example in the below query (or any improved query), if I would like to concatenate the birthplaces after alphabatically sorting, how can I do this:

```
SELECT ?x
       (group_concat(distinct ?name;separator="; ") as ?names)
       ?birthDate
       (group_concat(distinct ?birthplace;separator=", ") as ?birthPlaces)
       
WHERE {
  ?x owl:sameAs? dbpedia:Mann_Singh.
  ?x dbpprop:name ?name.
  ?x dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birthDate.
  ?x dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?birthplace.
  
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: there is no guarantee for the order of the bindings used in `group_concat`. You can get lucky and hope that the implementation of the underlying triple store does keep the sort order when using a subquery where you `order by ?birthPlace` - but in the end you could also do this your client code to ensure sorted concatenated birthplaces.